# How to compare two CGSize variables?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I want to make sure a `CGSize` is smaller or equal to another `CGSize`. like:

```
CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0);
CGSize secondSize = CGSizeMake(5.0,3.0);
if(firstSize <= secondSize){
    Do Stuff . . .
}
```

How would I compare this?

Comment: It depends on how you define "smaller".  Since you have two dimensions, do they both have to be smaller?  Or just the height? Just the width?  Or perhaps the area of the defined rectangle?

Comment: smaller is at least 1 dimension is smaller while the second dimension isn't larger (could be equal).

Comment: Okay, so total area doesn't matter?  If you have one box that is 100x100 and another box that is 101x25, then by your definition, it is bigger?

Comment: Presumably Dvir wants to know if the area described by one size can fit inside the area described by another.

Comment: @KevinBallard probably, just making sure.  :)

Comment: Last question, what about rotation?  For instance, what if box 1 is 100x25 and box 2 is 24x99?  Smaller or bigger?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Determine whether `firstSize` fits into `secondSize` without rotating:

```
if(firstSize.width <= secondSize.width && firstSize.height <= secondSize.height)
```

Comment: Actually, this will be true if they are the same size.  He wants "smaller" in at least one dimension.

Comment: @Inafziger: "smaller *or equal to*"

Comment: In that case the following should work: `if((firstSize.width <= secondSize.width && firstSize.height < secondSize.height) || firstSize.width < secondSize.width && firstSize.height <= secondSize.height)`. Anyway, using the `.width` and `.height` properties should do the trick.

Comment: "at least one dimension is smaller...." is my definition of "smaller".
this should work thank you. i just thought cocoa has something mor elegant for this.

Answer (score 120):

To check for equality you can use, **CGSizeEqualToSize** function by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

```
CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0);
CGSize secondSize = CGSizeMake(5.0,3.0);

if(CGSizeEqualToSize(firstSize, secondSize)) {
    //they are equal
}else{
    //they aren't equal
}
```

Comment: Dvir Levy looking for "smaller or equal to" as described in the question. In case `CGSizeEqualToSize()` returns false, we still don't know whether it's bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 5):

The following function determines if the rectangle of the CGSize in the first parameter fits wholly within or at the extent of the rectangle of the CGSize in the second parameter.

```
- (BOOL)size:(CGSize)smallerSize isSmallerThanOrEqualToSize:(CGSize)largerSize {

    return CGRectContainsRect(
        CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, largerSize.width, largerSize.height),
        CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, smallerSize.width, smallerSize.height)
    );
}
```

Instead of writing the full logic yourself with difficult to read conditional statements, you can use the built-in, inline helper functions whose names are descriptive.

While I haven't done the research, this method is probably slower in execution than the accepted answer since it involves converting the two CGSizes to two CGRects C structs. Though it does have the advantage of being quicker to comprehend by the reader.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great case to use operator overloading.

Compare by area (i.e. is one `CGSize` larger in size than the other):

```
func <=(left: CGSize, right: CGSize) -> Bool {
    return (left.width * left.height) <= (right.width * right.height)
}
```

Or, compare by dimensions (i.e. would one `CGSize` fit into another):

```
func <=(left: CGSize, right: CGSize) -> Bool {
    return (left.width <= right.width) && (left.height <= right.height)
}
```

Obviously you can't include both versions globally in your project, so to be on the safe side you might want to consider making the function `private` to the current file.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(firstSize.width <= secondSize.width && firstSize.height <= secondSize.height &&
    firstSize.width*firstSize.height < secondSize.width*secondSize.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty straight forward extension for **Swift 4.0** on `CGSize`.
As OP states, this assumes that you are concerned with dimensions and not area.

```
import UIKit

extension CGSize {
    func isGreaterOrEqual(to size: CGSize) -> Bool {
        return width >= size.width &&
            height >= size.height
    }
}
```

You can then test it with the following values:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let smaller = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
let bigger = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)

let small = size.isGreaterOrEqual(to: smaller) // true
let big = size.isGreaterOrEqual(to: bigger) // false
let same = size.isGreaterOrEqual(to: size) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020714/1836420) answer. It should be safer because sometimes the value can like this `667.0000000000001`.

```
extension CGSize {
    static func <= (left: CGSize, right: CGSize) -> Bool {
        let delta = 0.001
        return (left.width - right.width) < delta && (left.height - right.height) < delta
    }
}
```